# Application submit problem

Tags: iphone, xcode, organizer

i just try to upload a new version binary of my approved app to itunes connect with organizer.
i double check the CFBundleVersion and other things.

when i click to validate or submit button, xcode asks me creditials and displays the correct version of app but after that nothing happens and i couldn't upload my binary.

anyone has the same problem ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Xcode will check against iTunes Connect and make sure that it is properly setup online, if everything verifies you should get a message saying so and that you can now submit. If theres anything wrong, you will get an error message.

If all else fails, clean your builds, restart your machine and try again. Either way you should be receiving some message.

Comment: that's strange, i did everything but still no message. i'm going to reinstall xcode.

Comment: No need to reinstall Xcode. Check Console and see if there are any issues behind the scenes.

Comment: checked :) nothing happens there too. but i just reinstall xcode and it works smoothly. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

XCode does not necessarily give you error messages.  I've frequently seen it just fail silently.  But, WrightsCS is correct.  If you open up the Console app, you might see something useful.  For example, I got this out of console

```
Program /usr/bin/codesign returned 1 : [/Users/joeschmoe/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Archived Applications/1312312-DF00-421E-BC73-FD01412AA.apparchive/MyAppName.app: code object is not signed
```

XCode has a really bad feature, where you can select a particular Configuration (e.g. Debug or Distribution) and set the Code Sign Identity for that particular configuration, but then not use the setting you just chose.  I've had to manually edit my project.pbxproj file, and set all the CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY or PROVISIONING_PROFILE lines by hand, restart XCode, and then finally have it take effect.  It's like XCode is reading parts of the pbxproj file that the Info properties editor isn't showing you.

Bad XCode, bad.

P.S.  If you're wondering whether it's really a good idea to manually edit project.pbxproj files, I don't know that Apple leaves freelance developers like myself much choice.  I have multiple clients, that obviously have multiple provisioning profiles.  I try to keep them sandboxed, but sometimes, it seems unavoidable to edit the project.pbxproj to change code signing identities when the logged on user doesn't have certain signing credentials in their keychain.  But, I digress.